# Command Line - Move here

Tags: command-line

I would like to move a file via the terminal using the `mv` command. The syntax is

`mv file_old_dir file_new_dir`

I am already in the directory where I want the file moved. I just did `mv file_old_dir` which didn't work.

How can I do this?

`mv file_old_dir "here"`

Answer (score 16):

You can use the dot (`.`), the `~+` [tilde expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/tilde), the `pwd` command or the $PWD variable to represent the current working directory (CWD). All these commands can do what you want:

1. `mv file_old_dir .`
2. `mv file_old_dir ~+`
3. `mv file_old_dir $(pwd)`
4. `mv file_old_dir $PWD`

Answer (score 7):

I am going to show some alternate ways using the `PWD` environment variable and `pwd` built-in of the shell.

You can the use the value of `PWD` environment variable that stores the name of current working directory:

```
mv file_old_dir "$PWD"
```

Or you can use the `pwd` built-in of shell that prints the current working directory (basically `pwd` shows the value of `PWD` variable by default):

```
mv file_old_dir "$(pwd)"
```